# Pentaho Analysis Report date format

Tags: pentaho

I'm fairly new to Pentaho. I have set it up on a linux server and am trying to build an analysis report in the web-browser accessed user console. One of my data sources is a date in the format yyyy-MM-dd. When this is put into a report it displays an additional 00:00:00.0 timestamp. [image: notice the formatting under Provider GL Period Name]

I have searched around the options in the Analysis Report editor. I have also edited the Data Source Model so that that dimension is recognized as a time dimension along with its source format.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem as well. What I did I added a text field and clicked the plus button for formula from value field. Used function =LEFT([your-date-field], 10)

This will remove the timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I tried to find an option to add a text field but can't. I do see a box for MDX expressions but only for Measure fields. Since this is a date it can't be part of a measure field.

My screen looks like this: [link](http://imgur.com/RRDxq2z). (I blocked out the data for confidentiality reasons).

I also tried looking in the Data Source Model editor but couldn't find an option to add text.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You are using pentaho reporting or not?

Comment: Ohhh you are using enterprise edition. I thought you are using pentaho reporting tool. When you right click the date field what you get?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Is Pentaho Reporting Tool the desktop software?
This is [what I get when I right-click the column](http://imgur.com/exQp6Xu)

Comment: It's the reporting tool by pentaho. Pentaho has three flavors bi server, pentaho data integration and pentaho reporting

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up about the different versions. All I have done so far is install the file `pentaho-business-analytics-6.1.0.1-196-x64.bin` on a linux box and I have been using the Pentaho user console through Google Chrome on my laptop.

Comment: is that field set as either a Timestamp or a Datetime field on the database? If so, try setting it to a Date only field or a String, instead. You will also need to change the data type on the Mondrian schema file.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the field type from Date type to Text type. 
1. Insert a new text field 
2. Go to Structure > Attributes 
3. Edit the value of the field by choosing your Date data

The new output will just be e.g. 2017-03-12